# IE 11 Replace Current DOM with new HTML page

Tags: javascript

I would like to replace (reload) the current HTML web page with new html string. The new HTML string looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><body>Hi</body></html>
```

Tried few options:

- document.write(). // It gives: Permission denied error on live server might be CSP issue, So wont use this approach
- iframe can not use (due to client restrictions)
- Blob // Doesn't support in IE

Any thoughts...

Comment: You can get whole document with `var doc = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document); ` and then replace it with your string but as soon as you reload the page it will be gone.

Comment: What about creating another page? When you know it's IE11, just redirect to that page.

Comment: That's seems one possible way.  However in our case the new HTML string (html page) came from server, so would prefer first not to store the file locally.